# Configuring Jenkins for CI

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins to SSH files from Git to our web servers (more for copying not performing build tasks) and have a couple of questions:

1. Is it OK to exclude the .git folder and .gitignore file in the build? If so, what is the best way to accomplish this? I am not sure what syntax to use.
2. Everytime I fire a build, I notice that the time stamp is changed on every file. Is there a way to only update changes since the last build? I tried using the plugin Changes Since Last Success, but had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Your objective is to get the files from a Git repo and to copy them on your web servers? The .git folder is mandatory as it contains all the Git history, I'm not sure you can exclude it.

Comment: Ok, perfect. How about pull the last commit part of my question? Any thoughts to that?

Comment: I have one solution by using your web servers as Jenkins slaves (to deploy your files from Git). Is it an acceptable solution?

Comment: Sure, What is the best way to set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution should be to connect your web servers as Jenkins slaves.

Please have a look to the following links to connect your web server machines to your master:

Windows slave: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Linux slave: http://docs.omnirom.org/Adding_a_Slave_node_to_Jenkins

Next, you can create a freestyle job to get the file from Git with a configuration like below.

Use a custom workspace to checkout the file in the relevant path:

[image]

Next, configure the SCM section to get your files from Git:

[image]

You can configure the Build triggers section to check your Git repo using a cron expression:

[image]

Another solution should be to use a post-commit hook on your Git server to trigger a Jenkins build every time something is committed.

Does it help? :)

Comment: Yes, it does. The article suggests I do not have to have Jenkins installed on the slave server. What are your thoughts?

Comment: In my answer, there are two links to install the Jenkins slave agent on Windows and Linux. You web servers are running on Linux?